# Visitor to Application is Facebook Page

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-page

Can you determine whether a visitor to your Facebook application is a user navigating Facebook as a Facebook Fan Page? This is so I can show a different message to a Facebook Fan Page in comparison to a regular user account.

Answer (score 0):

Nope... at least not from the signed request. You can browse to a tab application with a "page account" and there, even once you have "liked" the page as **your page** the signed request comes back without the "user_id" parameter. 
On a canvas app you get a message like this :

[image]

That message is pretty self explanatory.